# SSH Tunnel Acting like a Bridge

Tags: ssh

I have three boxes. Box 1 can ssh to Box 2 and Box 3. I want to be able to ssh from Box 2 to Box 3 via Box 1. How can I do this?

I tried this (but this doesn't work).

```
 on Box 1: ssh -t -R 9999:localhost:22 -N Box_2
 on Box 1: ssh -t -L 9999:localhost:9999 -N Box_3
```

So, that I can do this on Box 2:

```
 ssh localhost -p 9999
```

which will connect me directly to Box 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to arrange for `ssh` from box 2 to proxy through box 1, optionally using a `ControlMaster` connection so that everything is multiplexed over the same connection.  [This article](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) describes one way to set it up.

Comment: I looked at the article that you posted but the article describes a situation like: Box 1 > Box 2 > Box 3 where you can jump to Box 3 from Box 1. What I want is something like this: Box 2 < Box 1 > Box 3 . So that I can jump from Box 2 to Box 3 immediately.

Comment: That should just change where you do each step of it, not how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can setup the tunnels

```
box 1: ssh -R 9999:box3:22 box2

box 2: ssh -p 9999 localhost
```

The last command will take you to port 22 on box3 through box1.  The way you had it you ended up with port 9999 on box1 going to port 22 on box2.

Ironically, I'm writing this as my daughter watches the spongebob episode that is about playing in a box.

Comment: No, because box 1 can ssh to box 2 and can ssh to box 3. box 2 and box 3 cannot ssh to each other. The only way to connect box 2 and box 3 is via box 1.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. Usually people use box1 and box2 to mean go to box3 through box2. I see, you're initiating the tunnel from the network you want to go to so that you can get back into it.  I'll change my example to work for you.